# How does the overestimate prove shortest path tree?

Tags: graph-theory

I am trying to understand the solution to problem 4.7 to the Algorithms book by DPV in this [link](https://faculty.cc.gatech.edu/%7Erpeng/CS3510_F16/tests/t2practice.pdf).

Problem:
You are given a directed graph G = (V, E) with (possibly negative) weighted edges, along with a specific node s ∈ V and a tree T = (V, E'), E' ⊆ E. Give an algorithm that checks whether T is a shortest-path tree for G with starting point s. Your algorithm should run in linear time.

Solution:
Do a BFS on T to compute the distance from s to all vertices along the tree, let the value to u be d'[u]. Then check if for all edges u → v, we have d'[u] + l(u→v) ≥ d'[v].

If so, T is a shortest path tree, otherwise it’s not. Since for each u, d'[u] is the length of a path from s to u, these are overestimates to distances. So we can use it as an intermediate state in the Bellman-Ford algorithm, which means that these
distance are optimal if and only if no more update to d' can be made.

=====================================

I suppose BFS gives us d'[u] in increments of 1, and v is always after u?  Thus, we can see that:

d'[u] + l(u→v) ≥ d'[v].

However, how does this prove that T is the shortest-path tree?  What does it mean by "overestimates to distances"?

Comment: As stated, the optimality follows directly from the proof of optimality of Bellman-Ford. If you want to prove the optimality directly, you can reuse the method used in the proof of correctness of Bellman-Ford. Suppose you have a shortest path (starting from $s$) shorter than the one provided by the tree. Take this path up to the first edge not in the tree. By the principle of optimality, this path should also be a shortest path. Can you construct a shorter path using the tree?